# Стиль WPF не находит ресурс конвертера во время работы приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-шаблоны

Пишу приложение на C# NET 6.0 WPF. У меня есть такой словарь ресурсов:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                xmlns:widget="clr-namespace:Example.Widget"
                xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Example.Util">

<util:RadioSizeConverter x:Key="RadioSizeConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle" Stroke="#DBDBDB" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Transparent"
                             Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>

                    <Ellipse x:Name="innerCircle" Fill="Transparent">
                        <Ellipse.Width>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="outerCircle" 
                                 Converter="{StaticResource RadioSizeConverter}"/>
                        </Ellipse.Width>
                        <Ellipse.Height>
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="outerCircle" 
                                 Converter="{StaticResource RadioSizeConverter}"/>
                        </Ellipse.Height>
                    </Ellipse>

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="innerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="#F7BA0B"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="innerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Как можно заметить, в нем используется конвертер. Вот класс конвертера:

```
public class RadioSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double originalSize)
        {
            return originalSize * 0.75;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Вот так я использую мой стиль:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <RadioButton x:Name="one" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Width="80" Height="80" GroupName="group1" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="two" IsChecked="True" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Width="80" Height="80" GroupName="group1"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="three" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Width="80" Height="80" GroupName="group1" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

В визуальном редакторе это даже работает, но при запуске приложения выпадает исключение:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Нельзя создать неизвестный
> тип "{clr-namespace:Example.Util}RadioSizeConverter".": номер строки
> "6" и позиция в строке "6"."

Почему так? Как сделать, чтобы работало? Я видел множество примеров, где так работает, не могу понять в чем проблема. Все неймспейсы, пути и названия верные, проверил несколько раз. Файл со стилем включен в сборку как ресурс.

Comment: Вместо одного из `Converter="{StaticResource RadioSizeConverter}"` попробуйте написать `Converter="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type RadioSizeConverter}, ResourceKey=RadioSizeConverter}"`. Без гарантий успеха, но вдруг именно этого не хватает

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Кажется, я пропустил указание неймспейса, попробуйте так: `Converter="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type util:RadioSizeConverter}, ResourceKey=RadioSizeConverter}"`. Если тоже не поможет, то лучше сделайте минимальный самодостаточный пример (проект) и дайте ссылку на него в вопросе.

Comment: Все равно не помогает, та же ошибка.

Comment: Проверьте, что 100% стоит "Ресурс" в свойствах сборки. Также попробуйте поменять namespace с указанием еще и сборки (`assembly`) в конце, то есть что-то вроде этого `xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Example.Util;assembly=Example"`. Ну и последнее, попробуйте не "Ресурс", а "Страница" (но это уже на крайний случай)

Comment: Помогло добавление assembly. Не понимаю, почему оно не видит его без assembly.

Answer (score 1):

В комментарии дали ответ: нужно было указать namespace так:

> xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Example.Util;assembly=Example"